# When component renders I get 'Cannot read property 'params'

Tags: reactjs

Im getting a big headache.. I dont know what Im doing wrong here. When my Podcast.js component renders, I get 'Cannot read property 'params' of undefined... '

Someone that can point me in the right direction?

This is the parent component of Podcast:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavLinks from './components/NavLinks';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Podcast from './components/Podcast';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
        <NavLinks />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/podcast/:podID' component={Podcast} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my main Component (Podcast):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PodcastList from './PodcastList';

class Podcast extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      podcast: []
    };
  }

  // Fetches podID from props.match
  fetchPodcast () {
    const podID = this.props.match.params.podID

    fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=podcast&country=${podID}&media=podcast&entity=podcast&limit=20`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ podcast: data.results }));
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchPodcast()
  }

  // Check if new props is not the same as prevProps
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    // respond to parameter change
    let oldId = prevProps.match.params.podID
    let newId = this.props.match.params.podID
    if (newId !== oldId)
      this.fetchPodcast()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PodcastList />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Podcast;
```

This is the component thats list's all podcasts:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class PodcastList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Country ({this.props.match.params.podID}) </h2>
                <ul>
                {this.state.podcast.map(podcast =>
                    <li key={podcast.collectionId}>
                    <a
                    href={podcast.collectionId}>
                    {podcast.collectionName}</a>
                    </li>
                )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PodcastList;
```

Comment: Based on the error, my guess would be that `this.props.match` is not being provided. Mind sharing the parent component for `Podcast`?

Comment: Could you share your parent component code where you receive the props from?

Comment: I have added the parent component code in my question now :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you are using `react-router`. To have `match` prop of the React Router you have to decorate it by `withRouter` decorator of the module

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class PodcastList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Country ({this.props.match.params.podID}) </h2>
                <ul>
                {this.state.podcast.map(podcast =>
                    <li key={podcast.collectionId}>
                    <a
                    href={podcast.collectionId}>
                    {podcast.collectionName}</a>
                    </li>
                )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(PodcastList);
```

**UPDATE:**

One of the ways how to handle `podcast` prop in the `PodcastList`. The solutions fits all React recommendations and best practices.

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PodcastItem from './PodcastItem';

class Podcast extends PureComponent { // PureComponent is preferred here instead of Component

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 

    this.state = {
      podcast: []
    };
  }

  // Fetches podID from props.match
  fetchPodcast () {
    const podID = this.props.match.params.podID

    fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=podcast&country=${podID}&media=podcast&entity=podcast&limit=20`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ podcast: data.results }));
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchPodcast()
  }

  // Check if new props is not the same as prevProps
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    // respond to parameter change
    let oldId = prevProps.match.params.podID
    let newId = this.props.match.params.podID
    if (newId !== oldId)
      this.fetchPodcast()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Country ({this.props.match.params.podID}) </h2>
        <ul>
          {this.state.podcast.map(podcast => (
            <PodcastItem key={podcast.collectionId}> podcast={podcast} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Podcast;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

// Here Stateless function is enough
const PodcastItem = ({ podcast }) => (
  <li key={podcast.collectionId}>
    <a href={podcast.collectionId}>{podcast.collectionName}</a>
  </li>
);

export default PodcastItem;
```

Comment: Yes I am. I added the parent component of Podcast.js in my question. After testing your suggestion i get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'podcast' of null, instead.

Comment: Yes, because you don't have `this.state` in your `PodcastList` component. It's obviously a leak of implementation. You have to move the state into `PodcastList` or transfer the `podcast` via prop into the component.

Comment: Have posted one of the possible solutions of your issue

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me understand. Im still in the learning phase of understanding how everythng works in React. I really appreciate your willing to help. Thanks again :-)

Comment: This dosent work, after trying it out. Stateless function components cannot have refs?

Comment: It's not a `ref`. It's `href`. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the error comes from? Podcast or PodcastList ? Maybe because you're not passing the props down to `PodcastList` ?

Try:

```
<PodcastList {...this.props} {...this.state} />
```

Also, in the child component (`PodcastList`) use `this.props` and not `this.state`

Comment: It comes from Podcast.js. Tried with the answer you gave but then i get:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'podcast' of null. Updated my question with parent component.

Comment: @JonasAlvarson Try new answer. As you see, the error message changed , which suggest that the first problem was fixed by this. The second problem (as well as the first one) comes from `PodcastList` and not `Podcast` . You're trying to use state and props from its father Component without passing them.. Also, the state is being passed as props and not as state

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you so much. Do you think this is a good way to divide components? I mean, to have one smaller component that handles the rendering of the list?  If not, can you point to a more right way to do it?

Comment: No problem . Mmm yes, it seems like a correct solution . (Though maybe using redux store is a better solution than using state, but tha'ts another issue) @JonasAlvarson

Comment: Allright! Im still in the learning process, so i will need to learn Redux later.

Comment: Transferring entire state and props of the parent component into the child is very bad practice. Sorry, but this solution is obviously the worst one.